# open project's file by typing its relative path

Tags: visual-studio-code

Lets say I have project with following struct:

```
src/main.js
doc/some/deeply/nested/folder/struct/readme.md
```

and I want to open `doc/some/deeply/nested/folder/struct/readme.md` can I open some kind of "console" and paste path to `doc/some/deeply/nested/folder/struct/readme.md` hit enter and this file will be opened in VS code tab?

Comment: thanks, add this as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `readme` that file should be in the short list